# xref gets confused by similar class names

Tags: evil, elpy, jedi, xref

If I use `evil-jump-to-tag` or `xref-find-defintions` on an inherited class module whose name is the same as a class in my current project, I am taken to the definition in the current project.  I would expect to go to the definition given in the module.

Aside from renaming the class in my current project, how I can I navigate to the module?

## For example

Suppose `my_module.py` defines a custom `MainWindow` that I use in  `my_project.py`:

---

```
# my_module.py

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("My module!")
```

---

```
# my_project

class MainWindow(my_module.MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("My project calling my module!")
```

---

If my cursor is `|`, then a call to `evil-jump-to-tag` or `xref-find-defintions` at

```
# my_project.py
class MainWindow(my_module.MainWind|ow):
```

moves my cursor to

```
# my_project.py
class |MainWindow(my_module.MainWindow):
```

I would expect it to take me to

```
# my_module.py
class |MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
```

What can I do, aside from renaming the class in `my_project.py`, to help `xref` understand that `my_module.MainWindow` lives in `my_module.py`?

---

## Configuration details

I am using Gnu Emacs 26.1 on Windows 10 with Python 3.  I edit Python files with `elpy` and `evil`.  The `elpy-config` reads:

```
Elpy Configuration

Virtualenv........: venv (c:/projects/my_project/venv)
RPC Python........: 3.6.8 (c:/projects/my_project/venv/Scripts/python.exe)
Interactive Python: ipython (c:/projects/my_project/venv/Scripts/ipython.exe)
Emacs.............: 26.1
Elpy..............: 1.28.0
Jedi..............: 0.13.2
Rope..............: 0.11.0
Autopep8..........: 1.4.3
Yapf..............: 0.25.0
Black.............: 18.9b0
Syntax checker....: flake8.exe (c:/projects/my_project/venv/Scripts/flake8.exe)
```

I have not done any configuration for `xref`.  Until now, it has Just Worked™.